# Django Group by query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I am using django ORM for fetching data using group by query.
The raw postgresql query is-

```
select date_trunc('day', time) as Time ,count(status) from table where group_id='2177' and status=1 group by date_trunc('day', time) order by time desc limit 7 offset 0;
```

and it is returning the correct output..

```
        time              | count 
---------------------------+-------
2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |    12
2017-05-03 00:00:00+05:30 |    26
2017-05-02 00:00:00+05:30 |    25
2017-05-01 00:00:00+05:30 |    26
2017-04-30 00:00:00+05:30 |    26
2017-04-29 00:00:00+05:30 |    26
2017-04-28 00:00:00+05:30 |    26
```

(7 rows)

I am using django annotate function to acheive this - here is the django query -

```
  records = TableModel.objects.filter(                  
                       group_id=group_id,                                           
                       status=1,                                                                       
                       time__range = get_time_range(range)                                                                    
                       ).annotate(
                                  period=DateTrunc('day', 'time') ,
                                  count=Count('status')
                               ).annotate(
                                         period = DateTrunc('day', 'time')
                               ).order_by('-time')
```

On Debug, I found out that django is internally converting it to -

```
   SELECT "table"."id", "table"."time", "table"."status", "table"."group_id", DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time") AS "period", COUNT("table"."status") AS "count" FROM "table" WHERE ("table"."group_id" = '2177' AND "table"."status" = 1 AND "table"."time" BETWEEN '2017-04-28 11:47:21.421755+00:00' AND '2017-05-05 11:47:21.421755+00:00') GROUP BY "table"."id", DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time") ORDER BY "table"."time" DESC;
```

here is its o/p (it contains more number of rows)-

```
     id   |           time            | status               | group_id      |          period           | count 
  --------+---------------------------+----------------------+------------+---------------------------+-------
   267821 | 2017-05-04 10:36:13+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1
   267790 | 2017-05-04 09:36:35+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1
   267786 | 2017-05-04 09:30:44+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1
   267735 | 2017-05-04 08:36:09+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1
   267696 | 2017-05-04 07:36:32+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1
   267650 | 2017-05-04 06:36:14+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1
   267603 | 2017-05-04 05:36:14+05:30 |                    1 | 2177       | 2017-05-04 00:00:00+05:30 |     1

    ....
    ....
    (149 rows)
```

i.e by default it starts group by using (**id** , **DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time")** ) field although I have nowhere mentioned in y Django ORM Query. As a result , output will get changed.

Does Django ORM by default takes id field into consideration ?
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: why are you adding two annotate?

Comment: I tried to implement using a single annotate also ,but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fixed by -

```
  SELECT 1 as id ,DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time") AS "period", COUNT("table"."status") AS "count" FROM "table" WHERE "table"."group_id" = '2177' and "table"."status"=1 and time >= '2017-04-28 12:48:33.348682+00:00' and time <= '2017-05-05 12:48:33.348682+00:00' GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time"),period ORDER BY period DESC limit {} offset {};
```

by default, django needs to return id(primary_key) field .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TableModel.objects.filter(                  
       group_id=group_id,                                           
       status=1,                                                                       
       time__range = get_time_range(range)                                                                    
   ).annotate(
          period=DateTrunc('day', 'time') # Truncate to day and add to select query
   ).values('period') # Group By period
   .annotate(count=Count('status'))  # add count of the grouping to select
   .values('period', 'count') 
   .order_by('-time')
```

Comment: getting the same result :|

Comment: it is printing the same sql?

Comment: here it is - ** SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time") AS "period", COUNT("table"."status") AS "count" FROM "table" WHERE ("table"."time" BETWEEN '2017-04-28 12:48:33.348682+00:00' AND '2017-05-05 12:48:33.348682+00:00' AND "table"."status" = 1 AND "table"."group_id" = '2177') GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', "table"."time"), "table"."time" ORDER BY "table"."time" DESC;**

Comment: it now group by (date_trunc , time) .. o/p is also incorrect though